# Creating a Car Class with Acceleration and Braking

Tags: c#, class

EDIT: I have tried this a different way and updated my new code. I am now getting a few errors:
1.  'Car_Class_BBrantley.Car.Car()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
2. No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 0 arguments
3. No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 0 arguments 
These last two errors fall under the GetCarData(); lines which are under the two button sections.

Alright, so my task is to create an application that displays 3 main features: year, make, and speed of a car. The year and make are inputted with textboxes and the speed starts at 0.

There is an accelerate button which is supposed to add 5 to the speed every time it is pressed and a brake button which decreases the speed by 5 every time it is pressed.

I am having trouble using the class and form together to display the results. I need to display in a messagebox the make, year, and speed. I have been sitting here for hours and I am getting nowhere. I am getting the errors " speed does not exist in current context" and "car does not exist in current context" under my buttons. I am unsure of how I should go about fixing this.

Any and all help is much appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a mess. I have never worked with classes before.

Here is the form:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Car myCar;

        public Form1()
        {
            myCar = new Car;

            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void GetCarData(Car car)
        {

            try {
            myCar.Make = txtMake.Text;

            myCar.Year = int.Parse(txtModel.Text);

            myCar.Speed = 0;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Must enter a valid make and year model for the car. ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
            } 

        }

        private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }
        private void btnBrake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }


    }
}

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    If you would like to see the class:

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    class Car
    {
    private int year;
    private string make;
    private int speed;

    public Car()
    {
        this.year = 1994;
        this.make = "Ford";
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
    {
        this.year = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    public string Make
    {
        get { return make; }
        set { make = value; }
    }

    public int Year
    {
        get { return Year; }
        set { Year = value; }
    }

    public int Speed
    {
        get { return speed; }
        set { speed = value; }
    }

    public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
    {
        //Add check for speed limit ranges
        Speed += speedIncrement;
    }

    public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
    {
        //Add check for speed limit ranges
        Speed -= speedDecrement;
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't create a new car everytime, store the car in a member field at the form level and it will help.

Comment: oh man your naming conventions are really throwing me off

Comment: It's unclear what your question is.

Comment: You should try to follow C# naming guidelines: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: you are currently returning `Speed + 5` instead of actually incrementing `Speed` and returning the value. Try `return Speed += 5;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
public int AccSpeed
{
    get { return Speed + 5; }
}
```

.. says "*get a copy of the value in property `Speed` and increase that copy with five before returning the result*"

What you want is: "*increase the value of property `Speed` with five and then return the result*". That is done by using:

```
public int AccSpeed
{
    get 
    { 
        Speed = Speed + 5;  //shorter code: Speed += 5;
        return Speed;
    }
}
```

However, Properties should never change state of classes in the get methods. Anyone using your code would get really confused if it did.

Instead use a method to make it crystal clear:

```
public int Accelerate() 
{
    Speed += 5;
    return Speed;
}
```

Comment: `AccSpeed` and `DecSpeed` should be methods. Because they are *actions*.  Definitely agree.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your variables like this:

```
public int name { get; set; }
```

this automatically makes it a variable with a getter and setter.

As for the methods that increase speed etc. you could make a method like this fx:

```
public void AccSpeed() {
  Speed += 5;
}
```

As for the rest you should be able to figure it out from this.

EDIT: Elaboration.

As I think your confused on how classes work let me elaborate. In your class name you have included the type of car I'm guessing because the class is supposed to represent that certain type of car.

You shouldn't think like this in programming. Instead you should create a Car class that can represent any and all types of cars.

So maybe add a string variable called type, and insert that in the constructor fx. thereby declaring what particular type of car it is. Then simply call your class Car.

If you then later want to add methods to specific types of cars, you could make subclasses of your car class that extends the main car class.

Fx. like below. Then you add the additional methods a racing car should have to this class.

```
RacingCar : Car {
// class content
}
```

Comment: go easy. It's their first time with classes ;-)

Comment: You can't really program without knowing anything about inheritance. But I suppose I could have put it more simply :P