# From a Class to a Form

Tags: c#, class

EDIT: I have tried this a different way and updated my new code. I am now getting a few errors:

1. 'Car_Class_BBrantley.Car.Car()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial
2. No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 0 arguments
3. No overload for method 'GetCarData' takes 0 arguments 
   These last two errors fall under the GetCarData(); lines which are under the two button sections.

Alright, so my task is to create an application that displays 3 main features: year, make, and speed of a car. The year and make are inputted with textboxes and the speed starts at 0.

There is an accelerate button which is supposed to add 5 to the speed every time it is pressed and a brake button which decreases the speed by 5 every time it is pressed.

I am having trouble using the class and form together to display the results. I need to display in a messagebox the make, year, and speed. I have been sitting here for hours and I am getting nowhere. I am getting the errors " speed does not exist in current context" and "car does not exist in current context" under my buttons. I am unsure of how I should go about fixing this.

Any and all help is much appreciated. I'm sorry if this is a mess. I have never worked with classes before.

Here is the form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private Car myCar;

        public Form1()
        {
            myCar = new Car;    
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void GetCarData(Car car)
        {

            try 
            {
                myCar.Make = txtMake.Text;    
                myCar.Year = int.Parse(txtModel.Text);    
                myCar.Speed = 0;    
            }
                catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Concat("Must enter a valid make and year model for the car. ", ex.Message, "\r\n", ex.StackTrace));
            }                 
        }

        private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.AccSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }

        private void btnBrake_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GetCarData();
            myCar.DecSpeed(5);
            MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + myCar.Year + myCar.Make + " and it is     traveling " + myCar.Speed + " mph. ");
        }  
    }
}
```

If you would like to see the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Car_Class_BBrantley
{
    class Car
    {
        private int year;
        private string make;
        private int speed;

        public Car()
        {
            this.year = 1994;
            this.make = "Ford";
            this.speed = 0;
        }

        public Car(string make, int year, int speed)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.make = make;
            this.speed = speed;
        }

        public string Make
        {
            get { return make; }
            set { make = value; }
        }

        public int Year
        {
            get { return Year; }
            set { Year = value; }
        }

        public int Speed
        {
            get { return speed; }
            set { speed = value; }
        }

        public void AccSpeed(int speedIncrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed += speedIncrement;
        }

        public void DecSpeed(int speedDecrement)
        {
            //Add check for speed limit ranges
            Speed -= speedDecrement;
        }
    }     
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228079/creating-a-car-class-with-acceleration-and-braking  If you are still having a problem, edit your original question instead of reposting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't created an instance of the `Car` class.

In this method:

```
private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GetCarData(car);
     car.Accelerate += speed;
     MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + car.year + car.make + " and it is traveling " + speed + " mph. ");
}
```

You're trying to do something with `car` (`GetCarData(car)`)but... what car?

Create an instance of the Car class at the form level:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    Car car = new Car();
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to store the car somewhere within the form. If you need to use more cars, you should have some kind of collection, selecting a correct car depending on some of the parameters.

A simple example would be:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Car _car;
    public Form1()
    {
        _car = new Car();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
...
```

and then use the already created instance of car within the form, i.e.

```
   private void btnAcc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GetCarData(_car);

        _car.Accelerate(); //note the way you were using won't work on this line

        MessageBox.Show(" Your car is a " + _car.year + _car.make + " and it is traveling " + speed + " mph. ");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you may need to add another button to set the initial settings of the car, in that event handler method you initialize the car's Year, Speed and Model info by calling the GetCarData().  Then, remove the GetCarData() from the DecSpeed() and AccSpeed(), because you don't want to re-initialize everytime you Accelerate or Decelerate.